# Loading dll file inside eclipse java project

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am trying to add the file `sqljdbc_auth.dll` to the project library. I add the folder containing the dll as external class folder.

Here I am basically trying to connect to my SQL SERVER 2008 database using SQL drivers given by Microsoft.

My code is

```
private static void Connect(){
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:hostname:1433;databaseName=dbname;"

                + "user=username;password=password";
            java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(SQLException e2)
        {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`
```

I get the following error

```
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:b83147c7-b45a-4f35-b601-195a0aa9c32c
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<init>(AuthenticationJNI.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2229)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sagar.com.package1.T1.Connect(T1.java:21)
    at com.sagar.com.package1.T1.main(T1.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<clinit>(AuthenticationJNI.java:35)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Are you sure there is only a .dll library for it, no .jar?

Comment: I have already added the 2 external jar files  i.e. sqljdbc and sqljdbc4

Comment: Are the .dll and the jvm the same bit type (32bit/64bit)?

Comment: What version of the Microsoft JDBC driver are you using? You ***should*** be using the Type 4 drivers, which do not require any platform dependent (DLL) libraries to be loaded. Better yet, use [JTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Perception If you want to use Integrated Security (which uses your windows/active directory credentials to authenticate) then you need the dll, if you don't want to use Integrated Security, you don't need the dll.

Comment: @user544079 If you use Java 6 or higher, you should only use `sqljdbc4.jar` (and not include the `sqljdbc.jar`)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - he's not using integrated security. Not currently anyway - check out his JDBC URL.

Comment: @Perception The url in the question isn't valid anyway, so I just assumed it was anonimysed a bit too much. If you check the stacktrace it is actually using integrated security; I am not sure how the driver behaves when the server only allows integrated security

Comment: @NoBugs: yes, the sqljdbc_auth.dll is for x64 as it is a 64 bit PC.@Perception: I am using the Type 4 driver from Microsoft JDBC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a DLL from inside Eclipse, you either need to include the DLL in a location on the system `PATH`, or you need to explicitly specify the `java.library.path` property in the run configuration of Eclipse.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to add something like this to the VM parameters of the project's main class:

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64"
```

(specifying the path to the sqljdbc_auth.dll file). There's no need to change the environment PATH or Eclipse IDE jvm parameters.

For the project's main class, select menu option `Run As >> Run Configurations...`
[image: Run Configurations...]

Answer (score 1):

On windows platforms the Java.library.path defaults to the PATH environment variable. The simple solution is to copy the DLL into your path (e.g. windows/system32) and restart eclipse.  Also the DLL type must match the Java version ie if you're using 32bit Java then you should use the 32bit DLL